# Combine multiple OBX segments in ORU_R01 message hl7 using python hl7apy

Tags: python, python-3.x, hl7, hl7-v2

I am trying to create an HL7 RU_R01 message with multiple OBX segments. However, I cannot find a way to merge these segments together into the message.

Here's my code:

```
message = Message("ORU_R01", validation_level=VALIDATION_LEVEL.STRICT)
has_xxx_formatted = '2'

text_formatted = DEFAULT_HL7_TEXT["EN"]["XXXX"]

## MSH Segment
message.MSH.msh_3 = 'XXXXX'
message.msh.msh_4 = 'XXXXX'
message.msh.msh_9 = "ORU^R01^ORU_R01"
message.msh.msh_10 = ""
message.msh.msh_11 = ""

# patient details
message.ORU_R01_PATIENT_RESULT.ORU_R01_PATIENT.PID.pid_2 = "patient_id"
message.ORU_R01_PATIENT_RESULT.ORU_R01_PATIENT.PID.pid_3 = ""
message.ORU_R01_PATIENT_RESULT.ORU_R01_PATIENT.PID.pid_5 = ""

## OBR Segment -- frature details
message.ORU_R01_PATIENT_RESULT.ORU_R01_ORDER_OBSERVATION.OBR.obr_4 = "Observations"
message.ORU_R01_PATIENT_RESULT.ORU_R01_ORDER_OBSERVATION.OBR.obr_7 = f"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%f')[:-2]}"


# obx0
obx0 = Segment('OBX', version='2.5')
obx0.obx_1 = "1"
obx0.obx_2 = "HD"
obx0.obx_3 = "REFInstanceUID"
obx0.obx_5 = "ref_uid"
obx0.obx_11 = "F"

# obx1
obx1 = Segment('OBX', version='2.5')
obx1.obx_1 = "2"
obx1.obx_2 = "TX"
obx1.obx_3 = "Presence"
obx1.obx_5 = "XXXX"
obx1.obx_11 = "F"

# obx2
obx2 = Segment('OBX', version='2.5')
obx2.obx_1 = "3"
obx2.obx_2 = "TX"
obx2.obx_3 = "Result"
obx2.obx_5 = "XXXXX"
obx2.obx_11 = "F"
```

Now if I add these obx segments using:

```
message.ORU_R01_PATIENT_RESULT.ORU_R01_ORDER_OBSERVATION.ORU_R01_OBSERVATION.OBX.obx_1 = 1
# adds individual values of obx0
....

message.ORU_R01_PATIENT_RESULT.ORU_R01_ORDER_OBSERVATION.ORU_R01_OBSERVATION.OBX.obx_1 = 2
# adds individual values of obx1
....

message.ORU_R01_PATIENT_RESULT.ORU_R01_ORDER_OBSERVATION.ORU_R01_OBSERVATION.OBX.obx_1 = 3
    # adds individual values of obx2
    ....
```

It only adds the last OBX segment into the message.

If I try to add the convert the OBX segments into a group as suggested [here](https://github.com/crs4/hl7apy/issues/62):

```
name = 'MDM_T02_OBXNTE_SUPPGRP'
mdm_group = Group(name, version='2.5')
mdm_group.obx = obx0
mdm_group.add(obx1)
mdm_group.add(obx2)

message.ORU_R01_PATIENT_RESULT.ORU_R01_ORDER_OBSERVATION.ORU_R01_ORDER_OBSERVATION = mdm_group
```

I get the following error:

> InvalidName: Invalid name for Group: MDM_T02_OBXNTE_SUPPGRP

I'd like to know how to add these multiple segments into a single message after the OBR. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the correct way to add multiple segments is to add each `hl7apy.core.Segment` to it's individual `hl7apy.core.Group`. This is explained [here](https://msarfati.wordpress.com/2015/06/22/python-hl7-v2-x-and-hl7apy-hl7-construction-with-ormo01-and-orur01-part-2), and the [documentation](https://hapifhir.github.io/hapi-hl7v2/) from the java version of hl7apy is useful.

```
message = Message("ORU_R01", validation_level=VALIDATION_LEVEL.TOLERATED)
has_xxx_formatted = '2'

text_formatted = DEFAULT_HL7_TEXT["EN"]["XXXX"]

## MSH Segment
message.MSH.msh_3 = 'XXXXX'
message.msh.msh_4 = 'XXXXX'
message.msh.msh_9 = "ORU^R01^ORU_R01"
message.msh.msh_10 = ""
message.msh.msh_11 = ""

# patient details
message.ORU_R01_PATIENT_RESULT.ORU_R01_PATIENT.PID.pid_2 = "patient_id"
message.ORU_R01_PATIENT_RESULT.ORU_R01_PATIENT.PID.pid_3 = ""
message.ORU_R01_PATIENT_RESULT.ORU_R01_PATIENT.PID.pid_5 = ""

## OBR Segment -- frature details
message.ORU_R01_PATIENT_RESULT.ORU_R01_ORDER_OBSERVATION.OBR.obr_4 = "Observations"
message.ORU_R01_PATIENT_RESULT.ORU_R01_ORDER_OBSERVATION.OBR.obr_7 = f"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%f')[:-2]}"

obs_name = 'ORU_R01_OBSERVATION'

# obx0
obx0_group = Group(obs_name, version='2.5')
obx0 = Segment('OBX', version='2.5')
obx0.obx_1 = "1"
obx0.obx_2 = "HD"
obx0.obx_3 = "REFInstanceUID"
obx0.obx_5 = "ref_uid"
obx0.obx_11 = "F"
obx0_group.add(obx0)
message.ORU_R01_PATIENT_RESULT.ORU_R01_ORDER_OBSERVATION.add(obx0_group)

# obx1
name = 'ORU_R01_OBSERVATION'
obx1_group = Group(obs_name, version='2.5')
obx1 = Segment('OBX', version='2.5')
obx1.obx_1 = "2"
obx1.obx_2 = "TX"
obx1.obx_3 = "Presence"
obx1.obx_5 = "XXXX"
obx1.obx_11 = "F"
obx1_group.add(obx1)
message.ORU_R01_PATIENT_RESULT.ORU_R01_ORDER_OBSERVATION.add(obx1_group)

# obx2
name = 'ORU_R01_OBSERVATION'
obx2_group = Group(obs_name, version='2.5')
obx2 = Segment('OBX', version='2.5')
obx2.obx_1 = "3"
obx2.obx_2 = "TX"
obx2.obx_3 = "Result"
obx2.obx_5 = "XXXXX"
obx2.obx_11 = "F"
obx2_group.add(obx2)
message.ORU_R01_PATIENT_RESULT.ORU_R01_ORDER_OBSERVATION.add(obx2_group)
```

Also note that the validation level is set to tolerated `TOLERATED`. `STRICT` mode only works with a single OBX segment.

Now the validation works.

```
assert hl7.validate() is True
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the python libraries, so I won't be able to give you the exact syntax, but ORU_R01_OBSERVATION is a repeatable field that allows for a single OBX and multiple NTE segments. If I were to guess the code should be something like.

```
message.ORU_R01_PATIENT_RESULT.ORU_R01_ORDER_OBSERVATION.ORU_R01_OBSERVATION[0].OBX.obx_1 = 1
# adds individual values of obx0
....

message.ORU_R01_PATIENT_RESULT.ORU_R01_ORDER_OBSERVATION.ORU_R01_OBSERVATION[1].OBX.obx_1 = 2
# adds individual values of obx1
....

message.ORU_R01_PATIENT_RESULT.ORU_R01_ORDER_OBSERVATION.ORU_R01_OBSERVATION[2].OBX.obx_1 = 3
    # adds individual values of obx2
    ....
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the ORU_R01_OBSERVATION  doesn't directly accept multiple OBX segments, and gives a validation error

Comment: Correct an ORU_R01_OBSERVATION can only have 1 OBX.  But  the ORU_RO1_ORDER_OBSERVATION can have multiple ORU_R01_OBSERVATION.  Note the code above shows adding the index at the ORU_R01_OBSERVATION.